# Relationship between the integration of the square root and the square root of the integration

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

Is there any valid equality or inequality relationship between
$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sqrt{f(t)}dt$ and $\sqrt{\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)dt}$?

$f(t) \geq 0, \forall t\in \left [ t_1,t_2 \right ]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: by Cauchy-Schwarz we have
$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sqrt{f(t)}\;dt\leq \Big(\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)\;dt\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\;dt\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{t_2-t_1}\Big(\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)\;dt\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wonder how this can be modified for integrals taken over the entire space $\mathbb{R}^d$